# adf.mf.api.invokeMethod is not accessable giving reference error

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I am creating mobile application using Oracle MAF framework.
I have a feature that uses a local HTML "untiled.html".

The HTML content of `untitled.html` is

```
<html>
  <head><title>index</title></head>
  <body>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <script>
         if(typeof adf !="undefined" && adf.mf.api.invokeMethod)
               documnet.getElementById('output').innerText="ADF API IS DEFINED";
         else documnet.getElementById('output').innerText="ADF API IS NOT DEFINED";
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output returned is **ADF API IS NOT DEFINED** why am i not able to reference the adf JS API from my Script Tag.

I am following this MAF page for API reference

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf222/mobile/js-ref/adf.mf.api.html

I want to use the `invokeMethod` method of `adf.mf.api` to invoke a java method from the javascript accrording to the reference above it should be possible.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem why is it not defined according to the docs of MAF oracle it should be available.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf222/mobile/js-ref/adf.mf.api.html#invokeMethod

Comment: sorry, ignore me, I thought this was something you were attempting in a web browser

Comment: is `adf.mf.api.invokeMethod` supposed to be javascript, or java?

Comment: @JaromandaX its suppose to be a javascript method that allows invoking a method in java class from inside the webview in ios.